# Does sizeof(pointer) depend on the object type?

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

I'm trying to understand what a pointer to an object means. I'm wondering if `A` is an incomplete type, why is a pointer to `A` a complete type. Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class B; //B is incomplete type here

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(B*));//4
}
```

Please explain why does `sizeof(B*)` return 4? What exactly does a pointer to an object represent in memory?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Such comment applicable to any question.

Comment: No, not really. "What is a pointer" => yes

Comment: No it isn't. There are many non-newbie questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please explain why sizeof(B*) return 4?

It returns 4 because size of a pointer variable is 4 in your system.

> What exactly pointer to object represents in memory?

Objects reside in memory, and pointer to an object contains the starting memory address of that object. For example, if your `B` object has size 100 Byte, and it is placed in 1024-1123(100 Bytes)  memory location, then a pointer to that object will hold the value `024 (starting address).

> Is pointer to sizeof depends on the object type?

I guess you meant *does pointer size depends on object type?*. No, since  pointers contain  an address, it's size depends on address space of your system, not type of object it points to.

Comment: It means that a pointer is 4 bytes *for that particular pointer type*. On most systems, all object pointers are the same size, but the language standard permits different pointer types to have different sizes.

Comment: Pointer exists into the processor internal or it is just abstraction of programming language?

Comment: @KeithThompson, I did not know that. Could you please give me some reference, I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: @St.Antario, your question is wrong. Nothing is in processor internals. pointer is a language artifact that holds value of memory address (primary storage), and processor use that value to perform read/write on that specific memory location.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to an object represents the address of the object in memory. If in your case it is 4 bytes, it means that you have a 32 bit address space (either the OS, or your program is built in 32bits). To maintain the address of an object you don't really need any knowledge of the object, so a pointer to an incomplete type is fine.

Note that none of this applies to pointers to members, which are a completely different beast.